# How to Copy and Paste Into Text File and Save Based on Column Row Data

Tags: excel, vba, text

I have a question on saving data from an Excel Sheet to a .txt file. I need to copy each cell from Column R of my Workbook and for each cell in Column R to create a .txt file, paste the data, and save it based on the same row column A data. This will create a text file for each line item in Column R and name the file based on the same row column A value. I have limited experience with VBA. Below is a sample of the data.

[image]

Comment: Your post starts "I have a question.." and yet I'm struggling to find one to answer. If you've written some code and having problems getting it to work, we'll need to see that in order to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is some VBA that loops through all rows on a worksheet, creates a text file in the folder specified named after the data in column A, and writes the data in column R to it.

```
Sub sSaveData(strFolder As String)
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim intFile As Integer
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    lngLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For lngLoop1 = 1 To lngLastRow
        strFile = strFolder & ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1) & ".txt"
        intFile = FreeFile
        Open strFile For Output As intFile
        Print #intFile, ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 18)
        Close #intFile
    Next lngLoop1
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Nothing
    Reset
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & "sSaveData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the code. However, I'm trying to run it and nothing happens @applecore

Comment: Place the code in a module in Excel. Then from the immediate window, `Call sSaveData("C:\test")`

Comment: Holy-moly, you are incredible. This saves me so much time. Thank you!